# SQL COUNT that includes 0 values

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

have a query that lists that amount of jobs for each day over a 7 day period.
works fine but it doesn't include 0 results.

what do i need to do get have it include 0 results.

```
select date_received, count(*)
from calls with (nolock)
where contract = 'BLAH'
and date_received between DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()-1
group by date_Received
order by date_received
```

this query produces results for 6 days, the 7th day has 0 calls, but that day to be included.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table, ie, a table that has a single row for every date?

Comment: You'll need to use a calendar table or similar and use that to perform a `LEFT JOIN` with the `calls` table

Comment: no, all the data is in the calls table.
i'm just counting the amount of records for each particular date.

thought i could use an ISNULL somewhere.

Comment: @chenks you misunderstand. You need to create a calendar table and then bam you can join any of your dates to it and bam every day will be there.

Comment: OK, but what if i'm doing the count against a field that isn't a date though?

obviously the solution would not involve a calendar table.

in this instance a date field is being used, but next time it might not be.

Comment: `between DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()-1` will give you a full count for 6 days and a partial count for the 2 days on either side.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a calendar table, you can do:

```
SELECT  A.[Date] date_received,
        COUNT(*) N
FROM dbo.Calendar A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM dbo.calls
            WHERE contract = 'BLAH') B
    ON A.[Date] = B.date_received
WHERE A.[Date] >= DATEADD(DAY,-8,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
AND A.[Date] <= DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
GROUP BY A.[Date]
```

If not, you can use a CTE for you calendar table:

```
;WITH Calendar AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1*number,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) [Date]
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
    AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 8
)
SELECT  A.[Date] date_received,
        COUNT(*) N
FROM Calendar A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM dbo.calls
            WHERE contract = 'BLAH') B
    ON A.[Date] = B.date_received
GROUP BY A.[Date]
```